# Inaccurate citation rate of book on Google Scholar

Tags: citations, google-scholar

The problem: incorrect citation rate of my 2001 book. In early 2023 Google Scholar changed pub date to 2011; after pub date error the cumulative citation rate fell from 10,00+ to 2000+. Can the citation rate be corrected/edited?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Google…

Comment: Assuming your profile name is your actual name, setup a Google Scholar account to claim your articles. That _may_ let you edit the citation details.